# Creating a list of variable types in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Perhaps there is a much simplier way to do this but I do not know. I am trying to create a list of the variable types in R. I have a dataframe with about 20 variables and I want to be create a list where each element is the class of the variable in its corresponding position.

Lets say the dataframe is called USData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Call *class* on your data frame using lapply**:

```
lapply(data_frame, class)
```